# Laravel won't load the Blade templates from my package

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

In my Laravel 5.5 application, I have created a package which is structured like so:

```
src/
src/Providers
src/Views
(..)
```

The ServiceProvider for my package, located in the `src/Providers` folder, registers the views using:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../Views', 'package');
}
```

Now, when trying to use any given view from that package in a main application Blade template like this...

```
@include('package::view')
```

...I get the following error: `No hint path defined for [package].`

According to the docs, it's supposed to work like this, though. What am I missing?

Note: The ServiceProvider is correctly added to my `app.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the rather trivial reason:

Before using a View file that's being registered in a deferred package ServiceProvider, one has to make sure that the ServiceProvider has been loaded (thus also registering the View).

Setting the ServiceProvider to be loaded eagerly solved the problem.

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: What it means? What should I do to be able to use @include()?